# WordPress - how to get all products in JSON?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, wordpress-database

I ve been at this for a few days now. I want to read the products from the database and return them in a JSON to the front page so I can use it. The problem is i dont even know how to read form db.
I ve tried making a plugin but i dont know how to do that either. I ve tried making a separate php script and using global $wpdb but no response. Any help appreciated.

I tried this in a php script.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );

echo $results;

?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
   // gets the global $wpdb variable
   global $wpdb;

   // put the query in its on variable to be able to include your database prefix
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."options WHERE option_id = 1";

   // get database results from the query and stores it as a stdObject
   $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

   // if something is found, convert the resulting stdObject into a json object
   if ($results) {
      $json = json_encode($results);
      print_r($json);
   }
?>
```

This should return your json string. I ran it myself on my wordpress installation and it worked without a hitch.

For me, this returned:

```
[{"option_id":"1","option_name":"siteurl","option_value":"https://your_url_here.com","autoload":"yes"}]
```

**EDIT**

This can be included in a plugin or in [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Another note: if you'd turn on debugging you'd see that you can't echo arrays out as a string :) You'd need to do this:

`<?php print_r($result); ?>`

Comment: for me it does not return anything, should this code be written in any php script or as a plugin? Please help me as I have no ideea as how to fix this.

Comment: sorry for the late response, only now I had some more free time, do you happen to know how to get the query result and use it in main page javascipt? Basically how to get the object out of the loop in another function outside.